# Fire onbeforeunload confirm alert for external sites only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I am using window.onbeforeunload method to show confirm message if user leaves website.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return textMsg;
};
```

But I need this to be fired only if user navigates to external web-site or closes window.

So how to cancel this confirm message for all XHR inside same domain and form submit etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnUnload message needed for external links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921206/onunload-message-needed-for-external-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (untested code):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return textMsg;
};

$('a:not([href^="http"])').on('click', function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null; // prevent message
});

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null; // prevent message
});
```

This will prevent the event from triggering if links do not start with `http` (external links) and for `<form>` submits. Looking for a solution for window closing at the moment.

Comment: how about using window.location? It should't appear too.

Comment: What would you do with it?

Comment: I am using both links and window.location to redirect to response url. 
And If I select elements byTagName , then href method returns full url with http

Comment: the solution works. But is there any way to cancel popup on page refresh too?

Comment: Thanks, solution helped.In the end we skipped detecting browser refresh