# Pop-up when leaving website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been asked to have a pop-up when visitors leave the site asking them if they really want to leave. This pop-up will only show if their shopping cart has items in it.

I can easily limit the pop-up to when the cart has items, however the issue I'm having is that even clicking an internal link loads the pop-up - how can I have it so this only comes up when actually leaving the site.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "some message about leaving";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I would consider telling your boss that there is no better way of antagonizing your users than showing them a popup when they try and leave the page.

Comment: How do you know when they're leaving the site? The only option would be to attach a click handler to every link and detach the `onbeforeunload` if it's a link to the same domain. The better answer would be to work-flow your shopping cart and when the user's session timeouts, maybe send them a reminder email "Hey, you still have items in your cart".

Comment: When have you ever tried to leave a site, been shown a popup that says "do you really want to leave?" and decided not to leave?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408083/fire-onbeforeunload-confirm-alert-for-external-sites-only

Comment: @bhspencer I tried that already, no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a link is clicked, it will tell you in `e.target.activeElement`. You can check if it's a link there:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(e)
{
    var $element = $(e.target.activeElement);
    if ($element.prop("tagName") !== "A") {
        return "some message about leaving";
    }
}
```

Note: You can add additional conditions checking `$element.attr("href")` to make sure it displays the message for links that aren't your site.

Comment: Also, I agree with everyone who's saying you shouldn't do this, but I know sometimes developers don't get the last word or a client demands a specific functionality. If you can, try to convince them that an `onbeforeunload` event should only be used when the user is going to lose information they've entered.

Answer (score 2):

Alright first of all: Don't do this. Please. It's super-annoying for users. Just make sure the shopping cart items are stored on the server or in a cookie so users can always go back to the site.

Looking at this related question: [How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event) it can't be done easily.

Instead of using `onbeforeunload`, either attach a click handler to external links on your site that shows the popup, or attach a click handler to all links that checks if the link is external or not.

Again, don't do this...

Comment: What about to prevent users from accidentally aborting a file upload? How would you solve it otherwise?

Comment: @simon yes, there are definitely scenarios in which it makes sense. But the one mentioned in the question isn't one of them in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the URL of a clicked link item, and check if it's on the same domain. Put this in an if not statement, with the current code inside.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to control it to enable and disable the behavior, something like this:

```
<script>
  var beforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'some message about leaving';

    (event || window.event).returnValue = message; // Gecko + IE
    return message;                                // Webkit, Safari, Chrome...
  };

  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload);
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload);
</script>
```

this is going to remove the `beforeunload` event whenever a link is clicked on the page.

Answer (score -1):

One way, and again, I wouldn't recommend doing this either - the user should be able to leave your site without receiving a warning - but you could unregister the event if a link has been clicked:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    return true; // continue
});
```