# jquery unload when leaving site not page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to sort out a way to trigger a bootstrap modal when the user navigates away from my site, not an individual page. Please before this gets marked as a duplicate, I have tried several different solutions, mainly this on: [Display a warning when leaving the site, not just the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365994/display-a-warning-when-leaving-the-site-not-just-the-page)

With this solution, it is not working as expected. I am getting browser alerts with every page navigation and should be getting them only when leaving the site. Here is my supporting code:

```
window.localLinkClicked = false;

$("a").on("click", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    // check if the link is relative or to your domain
    if (! /^http?:\/\/./.test(url) || /http?:\/\/app\.tendesign\.us/.test(url)) {
        window.localLinkClicked = true;
    }
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (window.localLinkClicked) {
        alert('do stuff');// do stuff
    } else {
        alert('dont do stuff');// don't
    }
}
```

I also want the user to be warned not just by clicking on the link, but closing browser tab etc...

Answer (score 1):

This script challenge got my focus.
Thanks to you, Sandra, who gave me the opportunity of a fun code time on a boring monday evening.

**First**, I had in mind *(because I've read it somewhere... I don't know when)* that the `beforeunload` event is handled differently depending on the browser and is, therefore, not a safe option.
For example, Chrome is not allowing an `alert` or a `prompt` on that event, which is exactly what you tried.

But it still, it allows a function to run.
Based on [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325742/2159528), I've tested something for you.

As of 2017, the message returned (as suggested in the 2012 answer) is not displayed in Chrome.
But a `return true;` works as expected with a default Chrome message:

[image]

**Now**, You don't want this function binded to the `beforeunload` event to execute if the target that triggered the event is an internal link.

**And I've added** to requirements : "Not on page refresh!"
*(`keydown` on <kbd>F5</kbd>)*

### Okay.

So here is what I have now, which triggers on close tab/browser and on external link click only.
(Taking account of full and/or relative URL).

I've tested it only on Chrome, which I think is the most severe on this event.
It's working.

And this code is fully ["Rubber Duck"](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) compliant.
Cheers!
;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("Page has just loaded.");

    // Flag to determine if a link click is local or external.
    window.localLinkClicked = false;

    // flag for the refresh key [F5]
    var refreshKey=false;

    // Link click handler.
    $("a").on("click", function(e) {

        // Get the link URL
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        console.log("Link clicked. URL: "+url);

        // Check if the link is relative to your domain:

        // [SUB_DOMAIN] example: www
        // [DOMAIN] example: google
        // [TLD] example: com
        // This regexp (regular expression) takes in account secured and unsecured domains (http:// and https://)

        if ( !/^(http)(s?):\/\//.test(url) || /^(http)(s?):\/\/[SUB-DOMAIN]\.[DOMAIN]\.[TLD]\//.test(url) ) {
            window.localLinkClicked = true;
        }else{
            window.localLinkClicked = false;
        }
        console.log("Local click ? " + window.localLinkClicked);

        if (!window.localLinkClicked) {
            var leave = confirm("Do you really want to leave our website to follow this link?");
            if(leave){
                refreshKey=true;
                alert("Okay, see you soon!");
            }else{
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("User has cancelled his navigation.")
            }
        }

        // Reset the local click flag
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.localLinkClicked = false;
        },10);
    });

    // Handler to detect the refresh key
    $(window).on("keydown",function(e){
        //console.log(e.which);

        if(e.which==116 ){
            console.log("User is REFRESHING the page. Do not trigger the confirm to leave.");
            refreshKey=true;
        }else{
            refreshKey=false;
        }
    });

    // On beforeunload event handler.
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
        if(typeof(e)!="undefined" && e.target.tagName!="undefined" && (!refreshKey && !window.localLinkClicked) ){
            return true;
        }

    });
});
```